# Writing Date,Time, Filecount and Filenames to a file in Bash/Linux

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Hey currently im using this command :
$ echo "$(date) $(ls -1 | wc -l)" >> /home/hive/landing/info.txt
which gives me an output like :
Wed Aug 26 12:43:00 PKT 2015 8
Which is the (Date Time Count)

Is there any way to add file names along with the count?

Comment: Are you concerned with the names of the files in the current directory?

Comment: Yes, the current dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following :

```
echo "$(date) $(ls -1 | wc -l) $(ls | tr "\n" " ")" >> /home/hive/landing/info.txt
```

`tr` stands for the "translate" command, and will change the `\n` to spaces in the output of `ls`

Answer (score 0):

You can take a stab at it from another angle. You can simply read all filenames into an array (`a` below), you can loop through the array writing the filenames, then finally write the number of files from the array-length and the date:

```
 #!/bin/bash

ofile=${1:-/home/hive/landing/info.txt}

## read all files into array 'a'
a=( * )

## write the filenames
for i in ${a[@]}; do 
    printf "%s\n" "$i" >> "$ofile"
done 

echo "number of files: ${#a[@]}" >> "$ofile"   ## write number of files
echo "$(date)" >> "$ofile"                     ## write date
```

Maybe that will give you another way to approach the problem. You ofile (output file) will contain the list of filenames, the count and the date.

As a **one-liner**

```
a=( * ); for i in ${a[@]}; do printf "%s\n" "$i"; done; \
echo "number of files: ${#a[@]}"; echo "$(date)"
```

(shown with a line-continuation for ease of reading)